# Custom Module depends on a specific version of another module?

Tags: module, xml, dependency

Let's say I have 2 modules Foo_BarA and Foo_BarB. We could declare Foo_BarB's dependency on Foo_BarA in app/etc/modules/Foo_BarB.xml like this:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Foo_BarB>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Foo_BarA/>
      </depends>
    </Foo_BarB>
  </modules>
</config>
```

But is it possible to specify the minimum required version of Foo_BarA as well, in Foo_BarB.xml?

e.g. something like this maybe?

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Foo_BarB>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Foo_BarA>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </Foo_BarA>
      </depends>
    </Foo_BarB>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in the way you mentioned above, but what you can do is add a check in your `Foo_BarB` extension to check if the version of `Foo_BarA` is 2.0.1. You could use the code below:

```
return (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->modules->Foo_Bar!->version;
```

Comment: Maybe add that to an install script?